# Decoding json given exception

Tags: c#, json, c#-4.0

I'm trying to get value of `js`,but I'm getting:

> A first chance exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'
>   occurred in System.Web.Extensions.dll
>
> Additional information: Type 'System.String' is not supported for
>   deserialization of an array.

How to fix this?

```
  string a = "{\"payload\":{\"js\":[\"abc\"]}}";
    JavaScriptSerializer ser = new JavaScriptSerializer();
                JSONData j = ser.Deserialize<JSONData>(a);
                Console.WriteLine(j.payload.js.ToString());

    public class JSONData
    {
        public payload payload { get; set; }
    }
    public class payload
    {
        public string js { get; set; }
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your JSON:

```
{ "payload": { "js": ["abc"] } }
```

The member `js` isn't a string, it's an array of strings. Either modify your JSON to match your class structure:

```
{ "payload": { "js": "abc" } }
```

...or modify your class structure to match your JSON:

```
public class payload
{
    public string[] js { get; set; }
}
```